# blocking exchanges in a 401-k

Tags: united-states, contract-law

My company is changing my 401k from Fidelity to Principal in the process I am not allowed to make an exchange for 30 days is this legal

Comment: Yes it is legal and common.  Thirty days is actually a short period, often they go out 90 days.

Comment: It's more than that.  The funds in the 401K will change.  My well-balanced portfolio got all moved into a Target <date_here> fund at the new 401K.